# Sorting a WebElement List to find specific Element (Selenium WebDriver/Java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'd like to search for a very specific WebElement in a very specific way.

The WebElement looks like this:

```
<aw>
    <div class="class">
        <h1>
            <a class="class1">TEXT TO FIND 1</a> 
        </h1>
        <p>
            <a class="class2"> TEXT TO FIND 2 </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</aw>
```

Both the `"text to find"`, may be written like this `"t e xt to fi nd"` (this makes obsolete contains()).
Because of this, I thought of subdividing both strings that I need to search in characters and then search for an element who contains all the characters, with max a 1 char tolerance.

Example of this^

getCorrectElement(String1, String2) -> returns WebElement

> Searching for "text" in (h1/a) [String1] and for "cat" in (p/a) [String2]

- Split both strings into array of characters
- Make a list of all elements who contain `"t"`;
- Get all the entries of that list containing `"e"`;
- Repeat until you have no words left/no element found,

  *`if` no element is found, try to see if there is a previous one (or maybe a combination of the characters (as always, we have 1 character tolerance), ex.* `1` `2` `3` *not found, but we have an element who matches* `2` *and* `3`, *if we have something like this, select this element (or better yet, add it to the new list).*
- Now we have a list that contains only WebElements which have "text" as (h1/a)
  we will use this to refine our search.
- We use the list we just made and do the exact same process as before.
- Operation finished (found element with both "text"(h1/a) and "cat"(p/a), return correct WebElement

This means that if `"Cool Catto"` was inputted, but there was no element matching it completely, it goes on the next element who matches most of it (max 1 char tolerance).

So `"Cool Catto"` = `"Col Catt"`, also `"Cool Catto"` = `"C o o l Catt o"`

I tried getting the xpath search toText(), but this xpath expression
`a[contains(text(), ' text to find ')]/../../p/a[contains(text(),' text to find')]`, returns only  `"text to find 2"` and not both.

If I use `[contains() and contains()]`, the expression returns elements who might only match a single `"text to find"`, while I need something that only matches both.

Also, I am pretty sure you can't do String->WebElement, So this method is always been wrong

How would I do something like this? Are there any more ways?
I thought of maps, but I haven't much experience with those.

Comment: Can you please sum up the exact condition (`text` + `HTML_TAG`) which you are trying to `locate`/`getText()`?

Answer (score 0):

The performance will be much worse, but you can return a list of possible elements and then perform more advanced filtering in your Java code. I'm using C# in my example, but the Java equivalent should be very similar.

```
var element = webDriver
    // Find all elements that are a direct child of the parent element
    .FindElements(By.CssLocator("aw > div.class > *"))
    // Get the first element matching the criteria
    .FirstOrDefault(e => {
        // Simply remove spaces. Regex could also be used
        string.Equals(e.Text.Replace(" ", ""), "TEXTTOFIND");
    });
```

I stated the performance will be worse because the WebDriver will have to query/serialize more objects, which if many can cause a noticeable delay. This is the pattern I've used only when a CSS or jquery selector was insufficient. [We] have hundreds of tests that take a few hours to run, so these delays were a considerable issue.